# Release Management 2013 email customization

Tags: email, release-management, ms-release-management

Is there a way to include a few more details to the Release Management 2013 release emails? Is there any way to do it by modifying the database or config files?

Answer (score 0):

No. The email templates are not modifiable.

What you **can** do is create your own PowerShell script to send whatever emails you want during the release process.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion of including a powerhsell script. Can the script be a part of the components that we create? I mean it should by default be included with every template we create.